# how to magnify part of a polar plot using spy library

Tags: polarplot, spy

I need to magnify a region around the origin of a polar plot by using the spy library. I already (successfully) used the library before in Cartersian coordinates. However, in this case, I am not sure how I should handle that "axis cs" and respective coordinates. Here the relevant part of my code:

```
\coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs?: 0.0?,0.0?);
\coordinate[very thin] (spyviewer) at (axis cs?: pi/4?,distance to origin?);
\spy[width=2.0cm,height=2.0cm] on (spypoint) in node [fill=white] at (spyviewer);
```

Could someone give me some hints on how to solve this? I could not find any suitable example so far. The basic problem is that I have several plots of different magnitude and the plots around the origin are hardly visible. Magnification is one option. Another option, since my plots are all axisymmetric, would be to plot the plots of lower magnitude on the first and fourth quadrants and those of higher magnitude on the second and third quadrants, so I would need two scales in this case. I think magnification is simpler and sufficient for my case.